# Ffmpeg. Can I loop to different frames in simultaneously

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

My abstract example(it doesn't work).

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "loop=20:1:1;loop=20:1:100" -y output.mp4`

Thanks.

Comment: Explain what you're trying to achieve. What should the final output look like?

Comment: I trying repeat frame, but I have case when user can set two or more different frame and I don't want do this operation for each frame separate. I want run only one command.

Comment: Should `output.mp4` contain only these looped frames, or should it also include the non-looped frames from `video.mp4`?